# SQL Variable not returning the correct sum

Tags: java, sql, sum, report

I have 3 variables in my current report that I am writing and the variables are
-Total WO
-Total SO
-Grand Total

The totalWO and totalSO variables are correctly adding up the quantity parameters they are being passed but for what ever reason when I make the grandTotal variable and pass it this variable expression:

```
($V{totalWO_QTY} + $V{totalSO_QTY})
```

When the report prints it displays all three variables as this"

```
TOTAL WO: 352
TOTAL SO: 1009
GRAND TOTAL: 16421
```

I can't figure out why it is doing this beacuse in the grandTotal variable expression I'm simply passing it and adding the two variable. If anyone could help me figure this out please let me know. Thank you!

***I can post any code you would like***

***Also i am using iReports to write these reports***

Comment: Please provide the Java code.

Comment: "I can post any code you would like" I'd like the source for Doom 4 please.

Comment: @colt heh you said **any** code :D

Comment: @Mena lol that request may not be too farfetch :p

Comment: @Shivam after looking at my SQL i realized that there isn't much code that's java. I tagged java because it does use netbeans IDE to compile the report. I have provided the paramerter settings and information and the numbers still are not "adding up" :/

Comment: how are total so and total wo defined?

Comment: @jkofron.e totalSO (sales order total) and totalWO (work order total) are both set up as variabels which are pulling from a field i created called "WOALLOCATED" and "SOALLOCATED" respectably. The actual variables are each set to a java.lang.double variables class, are set to a Sum calculation and are each pointing to their respected field expressions. i do have the 'reset' type set to report and the 'increment type' set to none at the moment as well. I'm using ***iReports to write these reports

Comment: Has the GrandTotal variable already been set before you added the WO and SO ?

Comment: @Amir I dont believe so because I added the grandTotal field AFTER i got the other two working :/ all i have done is set it to "totalSO + totalWO"

Comment: We need to see the variable declarations and also the data. Probably it's accumulating rather than displaying the last value of the other varables.

Answer (score 0):

@Amir in the comments actually helped me figure this out (indirectly). The issue was that 'increment type' for my WO and SO totals needed to be set to 'none' and the GRAND total needed to be set to 'column'. Before the grandTotal variable was set to 'increment type: none'. I still am not sure as to why it has to be that way but i know it is working now.

What helpe me was Amir's wording by saying "Probably it's accumulating rather than displaying the last value of the other variables".

Question is answered thanks to simple brainstorming- Thank you :)